# List and "pull-left" makes stair

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make something like blog comment. There is user's image at the left of comment and user's name. My code is as follows.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <%  @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <%= image_tag("test.jpg", :style=>"height:70px; width:auto; float:left") %>
      <h5 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= post.user.nickname %></h5>
      <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= post.body %></p>
    </li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
```

It makes stairs. Why? What should I do?

My CSS is only bootstrap.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the CSS.

Comment: Probably a `vertical-align:top` issue.

Comment: Consider using the [media object](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) coming with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because of the `float:left` image style. One way to resolve this is to add the `clearfix` class to the `list-group-item`

```
  <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <img src="//placehold.it/300x70" class="pull-left">
      <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">user</h5>
      <p class="list-group-item-text">body</p>
  </li>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/2kMdHMnaJl